# Anchor object or anchoring object

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

I'm confused with the word usage. I want to describe an object that stands out from the crowd and attracts attention. Which is better to say: anchor object, anchoring object, or anchored object?

Comment: An anchor holds something firmly, it doesn't attract attention, so I wouldn't use any of those. Try looking up 'conspicuous synonym'.

Comment: I can see some Google hits for "anchor object" in the context of interior design but it doesn't seem to have quite this meaning. "Statement" or "feature" might be better.

Answer (score 0):

A **landmark** is a location that is visually distinct from its surroundings, attracts attention, and is well known to people in the area, and usually to those from nearby as well. If the place is also worth visiting, it will attract tourists to the area.